# Tanuki Software Java Service Wrapper. Error: Could not find class

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I am trying to start my application as a service using the Tanuki Java Service Wrapper.

I have created the directories as mentioned for the WrapperSimpleApp.
This is my config file.

```
#encoding=UTF-8
# Configuration files must begin with a line specifying the encoding
#  of the the file.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Professional and Standard Editions of the Wrapper require a valid
#  License Key to start.  Licenses can be purchased or a trial license
#  requested on the following pages:
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
##include.debug

# The Wrapper will look for either of the following optional files for a
#  valid License Key.  License Key properties can optionally be included
#  directly in this configuration file.
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

# The following property will output information about which License Key(s)
#  are being found, and can aid in resolving any licensing problems.
#wrapper.license.debug=TRUE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Localization
#********************************************************************
# Specify the locale which the Wrapper should use.  By default the system
#  locale is used.
#wrapper.lang=en_US # en_US or ja_JP

# Specify the location of the Wrapper's language resources.  If these are
#  missing, the Wrapper will default to the en_US locale.
wrapper.lang.folder=../lang

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=c:/Prigram Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/jna/jna.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/jna/platform.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=../lib/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib/native

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=esq.logreader.DbTestDriver
wrapper.app.parameter.2=Event_Logger
wrapper.app.parameter.3=Event_Table
wrapper.app.parameter.4=Scouser
wrapper.app.parameter.5=12345

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Do not start if the pid file already exists.
wrapper.pidfile.strict=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=@app.long.name@

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=60
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1000=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1000=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1000=The JVM has run out of memory.
```

P.S: i have removed the rest of the part of config file, as i have kept it as it was in the default config file provided. Din want to make things messy and long in this post.

Error Message(Updated):

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.15
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Launching Startup thread.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Startup thread started.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Attempting to verify the binary signature.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | The file "D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin\wrapper.exe" is signed and the signature was verified.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   Signer Certificate:
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     Serial Number: 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |       00 97 06 fe b5 6e 56 cc cb 66 3a bb 55 a7 a0 e4 76 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     Issuer Name: UTN-USERFirst-Object
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     Subject Name: Tanuki Software Ltd.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   TimeStamp Certificate:
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     Serial Number: 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |       47 8a 8e fb 59 e1 d8 3f 0c e1 42 d2 a2 87 07 be 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     Issuer Name: UTN-USERFirst-Object
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |     Subject Name: COMODO Time Stamping Signer
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Startup thread stopped.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Release time: 2012/06/20 00:00:00
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Build time:   2012/06/20 17:50:00
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Timezone:     Pacific Standard Time (Pacific Daylight Time) Offset: 28800, hasDaylight: 1
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Using tick timer.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Current User: Scouser  Domain: Scouser-Umang
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Operating System ID: Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | 
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Environment variables (Source | Name=Value) BEGIN:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _PARAMETERS= 
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _REALPATH=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_BASE=wrapper
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_CONF="../conf/wrapper.conf"
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_CONF_DEFAULT=../conf/wrapper.conf
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_EXE=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin\wrapper.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | _WRAPPER_L_EXE=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin\wrapper-windows-x86-64.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | APPDATA=C:\Users\Scouser\AppData\Roaming
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | asl.log=Destination=file;OnFirstLog=command,environment,parent
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\rt.jar
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | COMPUTERNAME=SCOUSER-UMANG
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | ComSpec=C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | HOMEDRIVE=C:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | HOMEPATH=\Users\Scouser
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Scouser\AppData\Local
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | LOGONSERVER=\\SCOUSER-UMANG
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | OS=Windows_NT
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework DMS\1.3.03\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework DMS\1.3.03\64bit\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PHPRC=C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_REVISION=2502
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PROMPT=$P$G
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PSModulePath=C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | QTJAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | SESSIONNAME=Console
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | SSH_AGENT_PID=9128
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-zhvjHY8368/agent.8368
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | SystemDrive=C:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | SystemRoot=C:\windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | TEMP=C:\Users\Scouser\AppData\Local\Temp
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | TMP=C:\Users\Scouser\AppData\Local\Temp
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | USERDOMAIN=Scouser-Umang
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | USERNAME=Scouser
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Scouser
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P---- | windir=C:\windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_ARCH=x86
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_BIN_DIR=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_BITS=32
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_CONF_DIR=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\conf
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_FILE_SEPARATOR=\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_HOST_NAME=Scouser-Umang
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_HOSTNAME=Scouser-Umang
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   P--W- | WRAPPER_INIT_DIR=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_LANG=en
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_OS=windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_PATH_SEPARATOR=;
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_PID=6228
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_WORKING_DIR=D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\bin
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Environment variables END:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Use tick timer mutex=FALSE
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | active log file changed: ..\logs\wrapper.log
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:39 | Preparing to restart with mode 1.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | server listening on port 32002.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | Magic number for file C:\windows\system32\java.exe: 0x4d5a9000
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | Ping settings: wrapper.ping.interval=5, wrapper.ping.interval.logged=1, wrapper.ping.timeout=30
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | Launching a JVM...
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | Command: "C:\windows\system32\java.exe" -Djava.library.path="..\lib\\" -classpath "..\lib\wrapper.jar;..\lib\jna\jna.jar;..\lib\jna\platform.jar;..\lib\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar" -Dwrapper.key="Adm-N04uyX1nT_K1" -Dwrapper.port=32002 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=6228 -Dwrapper.version="3.5.15" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp ..bin\esq.logreader.DbTestDriver Event_Logger Event_Table Scouser 12345
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | JVM started (PID=11784)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main   Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@92e78c
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: JVM #1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Running a 32-bit JVM.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager package information:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Title: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Vendor: Tanuki Software, Ltd.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Version: 3.5.15
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Is Sealed?: False
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager protection domain:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Location: file:/D:/Umang/Documents/College/Eclipse%20Work/WindowsEventLogReader/lib/wrapper.jar
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:     Size: 119,430
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:     MD5: 2c0a68dc7fc3dec48d62674afafbfeb6
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Registering shutdown hook
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Using wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Registered MBean with Platform MBean Server: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper:type=WrapperManager
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Load native library.  There are multiple possible file names and the first to be found will be used.  Errors loading non-existing files is normal and is only a problem if they all fail.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Attempt to load native library with name: wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll  Result: Success!
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug:   Successfully loaded native library.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Loaded localized resources.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Calling native initialization method.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperJNI Debug: Initializing WrapperManager native library.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperJNI Debug: Java Executable: C:\windows\SysWOW64\java.exe
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperJNI Debug: Native Library: D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\lib\wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperJNI Debug: Windows version: 6.1.7601
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager: WARNING - The version of the Wrapper which launched this JVM is 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager:           "3.5.15" while the version of the native library 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager:           is "3.4.0".
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager:           The Wrapper may appear to work correctly but some features may
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager:           not function correctly.  This configuration has not been tested
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager:           and is not supported.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Java Version   : 1.7.0_09-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: OS Name        : Windows 7
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: OS Arch        : x86
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Control event monitor thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Startup runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperSimpleApp Error: Unable to locate the class ..bin\esq.logreader.DbTestDriver : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //bin\esq/logreader/DbTestDriver
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 |                   application.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager.stop(1) called by thread: main
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Backend not connected, not sending packet STOP : 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Pausing for 1,000ms to allow a clean shutdown...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | WrapperManager Debug: Stopped checking for control events.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:40 | Pause reading child process output to share cycles.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Thread, main, handling the shutdown process.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:41 | WrapperManager Debug: shutdownJVM(1) Thread: main
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:41 | WrapperManager Debug: wait for 0 shutdown locks to be released.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:41 | WrapperManager Debug: Backend not connected, not sending packet STOPPED : 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/14 19:04:42 | WrapperManager Debug: calling System.exit(1)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:42 | JVM process exited with a code of 1, setting the wrapper exit code to 1.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:42 | JVM exited while loading the application.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:42 | Preparing to restart with mode 2.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:42 | JVM was only running for 2 seconds leading to a failed restart count of 1.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:42 | Waiting 5 seconds before launching another JVM.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:43 | CTRL-C trapped.  Shutting down.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:43 | wrapperStopProcess(0, TRUE) called.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2012/11/14 19:04:43 | closing backend server.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2012/11/14 19:04:43 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

My question is what am i doing wrong. 
I tried applying the WrapperListener as well, the same error persists.

Is it possible that my directories arent kept in a proper manner.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what is Tanuki but you will need to post the entire error message for anyone to be able to help

Comment: Ok. Posted the error message. Hope someone can help. I think this is a beginners issue i am facing. Probably placing a file in a wrong directory somewhere. Tried looking around a lot.

Comment: Did you try using full paths?

Comment: I just tried that. The problem is, i have a Space in the path. 
It is, "D:\Umang\Documents\College\Eclipse Work\WindowsEventLogReader\". So here, it only reads till Eclipse. 
How do i escape that space. I tried putting the path in [].

Comment: Remembered that I *have* used Tanuki service wrapper. Just checked my conf file and realized we don't have spacey paths. Can you not install in a different path?

Comment: About to do that, but also a very big mistake i made was, i did not change the calsspath numbers :s . Relative paths work
SO now it can locate the WrapperSimpleApp class, but cannot locate my applications main class. It is in the bin folder inside the package esq/logreader. Do i need to specify bin in my path?

Comment: I have all the jars required in `wrapper.java.classpath.N` properties. You definitely need the application's entire classpath in these

Comment: I do have that as well, am not sure why it isnt able to locate the class i am trying to load for the service. 
Am updating my error log, if you can catch a mistake that would be great. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Do i need to have a .jar of the application i am trying to run as well? I think if i am to follow that method, i will have to use the 4th integration method provided by tanuki software

Comment: Yes, the classpath of the application that you are trying to run as service needs to be in the wrapper.java.classpath

Comment: No, i meant that do i need to pack my entire application in a jar file. I already have the necessary libraries i need for the application in the wrapper.java.classpath.

Comment: No, the app does not *have* to be in a jar, though that's the way it is usually done. But if there are bare classfiles then the folder has to be in the wrapper classpath

Comment: All my dependencies(libraries needed for application) are in a jar. Will look around a little, hopefully i will figure it out.
Will post the solution if i do find it. 

Thanks for the help @MiserableVariable

Answer (score 1):

The error about the native library is because the wrapper.dll is version 3.4.0 which the version of the Wrapper.exe and wrapper.jar are 3.5.15.  Please be sure to use the same version.

The main problem you are seeing is with the launching of the application.  The error is saying that the WrapperSimpleApp class's main method is not receiving the correct arguments.

Looking at your configuration file, the first argument is:
wrapper.app.parameter.1=esq.logreader.DbTestDriver

This looks correct.   But the command line looks like this:
..bin\esq.logreader.DbTestDriver

Are you sure that the wrapper.conf file you posted is the same as the one used to create the wrapper.log file?  From the log output, it looks like the following setting was being used:
wrapper.app.parameter.1=..bin\esq.logreader.DbTestDriver

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: Hey, sorry about posting a slightly different config file. 
I got the application running fine now. But i had to put my application in a jar file.

What i am confused about is that, why did it not read the stand alone class file. I tried specifying the full path, the relative path with the bin folder(../bin/esq.logreader.DbTestDriver) and the relative path esq.logreader.DbTestDriver.

Comment: @UmangDesai: have you been able to resolve the problem? If not, please provide an update with the latest error message and the conf file. if you want to use the class file directly, you only need to add the directory, where the class file is located to the wrapper.java.classpath.<n> and then as wrapper.app.parameter use the name of the mainclass, i.e. esq.logreader.DbTestDriver

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error.  For me the solution was making sure the matching wrapper.dll version was located in the search paths defined by
the "wrapper.java.library.path." property entries [1] in the wrapper.conf file

1 - https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-java-library-path-n.html.